# use of SAFE rule for initial feature selection

Tags: optimization, lasso, regularization

I am building a binary classification model with a feature matrix of size 100k x 100k where the rows/columns represent documents/ngrams (1,2,..., 5).  ngram must be in at least .5% of the documents to be a column.  Re-writing the SAFE rule

$$
|\boldsymbol{x}_j^\intercal \boldsymbol{y}| < f \lambda_{\text max} - ||\boldsymbol{x}_j||_2 ||\boldsymbol{y}||_2 \left(1 - f\right)  \quad \text{where} \quad f = \lambda / \lambda_{\text max} 
$$

I constructed a table (f | #features) which shows the the number of features which would *survive* for 1000 $f$ values between 0 and 1 (I realize lower bound for f will be $\lambda_{\text min}/\lambda_{\text max}$ which may be different from 0).  Suppose I want to select 5000 features, I look at the row for which #features is closest to 5000 and get the corresponding f* value.  The SAFE formula is then used to identify the features for that f*  so that the matrix is reduced to 1000k x ~5000 and the LASSO algorithm is run on that matrix.

For the experiments below I used a sparse binary feature matrix indicating the presence of an ngram in a document.

**Exp1:** selected 5k features as described above, ran LASSO with xval=5, used 1se to select final feature set.  Features make sense, model looks good.

**Exp 2:** selected 500 features using SAFE.  The top 5 features (highest abs coef) from Exp 1 are not even in this list!

**Exp 3:** selected 20 features using SAFE.  None of the features selected make any sense.

Is my use of SAFE for dimensionality reduction as described above not correct?  I realize that it is a univariate selection method which is suggesting which coef should surely be zero, but I am a bit surprised about 2 & 3.  I am wondering if using 5k features in Exp1 is sufficient.